# New Catalina 10.5 desk screen

Tags: macbook-pro

How does one change the new Catalina 10.5 desk screen/ wallpaper?  It is lonely, barren, ugly. Like a dragon.

Answer (score 3):

1. Choose **Apple menu** [image]  > **System Preferences**.
2. Click **Desktop & Screen Saver**.
3. From the Desktop pane, select a folder of images on the left, then click an image on the right to change your desktop picture.
   [image]

In macOS Mojave or later, you can also choose from Dynamic Desktop images, which automatically change throughout the day based on the time of day in your location.